# React Firebase redirection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, routes, firebase-authentication

When the user is logged in or sign up I want to redirect to the dashboard page
In this case, I'm getting the console that user has signed in or up but the page is not going to dashboard

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

//in signin.js
 login = e => {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    const { router } = this.props;
    e.preventDefault();

    auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(user => {
        if (user) {
          console.log('user has signed in or up', user);
          return <Redirect to='/profile' />;
        } else {
          console.log('user signed out or still need to sign in', user);
          return <Redirect to='/signIn' />;
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };

//in App.js

render() {
    return (
      <Router>
          <Route exact path="/" component={SignIn} />
          <Route exact path="/signIn" component={SignIn} />
          <Route exact path="/signUp" component={SignUp} />
          <AuthorizedRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Profile} />
      </Router>
    );
  }
```

In sign up I even don't get console message  I think it's not necessary to check in signing up if user exist so how can I do in the sign-up

```js
 //in sign up.js
 signUp = e => {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    e.preventDefault();

    auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(user => {
        if (user) {
          console.log('user has signed in or up', user);
          return <Redirect to='/dashboard' />;
        } else {
          console.log('user signed out or still need to sign in', user);
          return <Redirect to='/signIn' />;
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

What redirection you are using? The code is not clear to answer the question right now.

`res.redirect("/user/add");`

You can use this method also based on the response.

Comment: I'm using react router redirection

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

Answer (score 0):

From the code provided, after a successful signIn, your Redirect URL should be '/dashboard' rather than '/profile'.

Your signUp function *should* produce some console output. If it's really not, that would mean the function isn't being (successfully) called.

Rather than using redirection in signing In/Up promises, a better approach is to use a single 'authentication state observer' using `onAuthStateChanged` that will respond to your sign In/Up/Out events and redirects accordingly. (See the Firebase guide on this topic: [Get Started with Firebase Authentication on Websites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start)) With this observer in place, your `signInWithEmailAndPassword` and `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` calls need only handle error responses.